# c# Simple TASK Cancel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I'm tying stop thread by nothing works. 
I was trying on 100 ways.
What is wrong ?
It is irritating

(I have to write some text here because stackoverflow.com don't allow me to send this post)(I have to write some text here because stackoverflow.com don't allow me to send this post)(I have to write some text here because stackoverflow.com don't allow me to send this post)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                work_for_task(ct);
            }, this.ct);
        }

        private void work_for_task(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (richTextBox2.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        richTextBox2.AppendText("I AM IN: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "\n");
                    });

                    Thread.Sleep(1400);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CANCELED");
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're only checking for task cancellation *once* - you should be checking it on each iteration of the loop. Also, instead of filling your post with bogus text, you should put *useful* text there. None of the text you've posted explains the bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve, or what you've tried beyond the code you've provided, or what happened.

Comment: You have right ... it was out of loop... I'm learning and I make sometimes stupid mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this instead of your `work_for_task` method:

```
private void work_for_task(CancellationToken ct)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return; 
        }
        if (richTextBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            richTextBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText("I AM IN: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "\n");
            });

            Thread.Sleep(1400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is bug with   -  ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); I just use "return;" and thread is finished. Thx

Comment: You don't need to check for `IsCancellationRequested`, or the break (unreachable code), just call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in the loop. See the equivalent code section of the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Also because `ct` is a public class member, its not required (or recommended) to also pass it as an argument to the method.

Comment: @mtoy yeah, you're right, I fixed it! If it helpd you anyway,  please mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: There is one problem - Thread is stoped but when I click button1 thread can't start again ... some ideas what is wrong ?

Comment: Ok I know - I need to create new CancellationTokenSource object.